# Squared distance to a closed embedded manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, stochastic-calculus, submanifold

In the **Proposition 1.2.8** in the book *"Stochastic Analysis on Manifold"* by Elton Hsu, he claimed that: 
Given a smooth closed embedded manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $d_{\mathbb{R}^N}( \cdot,\cdot)$ denote the Euclidean distance between any two points in $\mathbb{R}^N$, then within a small neighborhood of $M$, the function $f(x) := \inf_{y \in M} d^2_{\mathbb{R}^N} (x,y)$ is smooth

Is this claim true? Can you help me by giving a reference or a proof on this?

Comment: This is one consequence of the tubular neigbhorhood theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much